# How to remove an image from a component in Angular before a new one is obtained from API

Tags: angular, image, api, rendering

I have a child component that gets a picture from an api and display it on the template. The parent component contains a list of items, when the user select one of the items, a request is send to an api to get a picture that belongs to the item, the child component is displayed and the picture that belongs to that item is shown.

The problem I have is that when the user selects a new item from the list, the child component is displayed, but the picture from the previous item is shown until a request from the api is received and the new picture is rendered.

I want to avoid displaying the previous picture, since is confusing and inconsistent for the user. Any suggestions how to accomplish this are appreciated.

Here is the parent component template where the child component is called:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="shownColumns.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <div>
            <image-card [img64]="img64"></image-card> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

Child img64 @Input:
@Input()
  public set img64(value: blob) {
    this.loadingData = true;
    if (value) {
      this.image = value.base64Image;
      const objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.image;
      this.thumbnail = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Find loading gif image before request put it when data comes then change it

Comment: You could wrap the child component in a `ng-container` with a boolean flag. Set it to `true` or `false` when you try to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem it was setting the 'this.image' value to null on parent and child components at the beginning of the functions respectively.

Parent component where the service call the api:

```
displaySelectedItem(id: number) { 
    this.selectedImage = null; 
    this.selectedItemService. 
    getItemData(id).pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe((itemImage: ItemImage)=> (this.selectedImage = itemImage)); 
}
```

Child component:

```
@Input() 
public set itemImage(value: ItemImage) { 
    this.selectedImage = null; 
    if(value) {
        this.itemImage = value.itemImage
    }
}
```